# Cross-cutting "logical" scopes in multi-project sbt builds

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's say I have a build with a handful of subprojects that are related but have some logical classification above the sorts of things that the build is normally aware of.

For example, I might have a collection of subprojects

- Foo
- Bar
- Baz
- Quux
- Woof
- Oink

I know that Woof and Bar are part of what I'd call the server component. Baz is a common dependency of both, and Foo, Quux, and Oink are on the client side. The whole build is an aggregate of the various subprojects, but sometimes I'd just like to "focus" on the server side, or the client side, or whatever.

On one hand, I've considered nested aggregated projects, but I'm not sure how well that works with sbt's other functionality.

On the other, I was thinking of making custom scopes that cut across the subprojects. I'd like to be able to configure related projects with similar keys, so it is handy to be able to say that I'd like to update a certain key for the group of related projects.

What's a good approach for this sort of thing? Am I thinking about it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with the similar situation.

My solution was to break things out into sub-projects all in sbt, and use dependsOn to link the sub-projects. The nice unintended consequence here is that sub-projects with dependsOn mimic Maven dependencies perfectly. If you publish one of these, it will magically have maven dependencies for the others. Tools like eclipse and intelli will generally also see these dependency chains rather easily.

This gives you the option of keeping things in the same SBT project or not, with almost no difference in the end. They just all tie together at the 'maven-style' dependency. Using a local maven repo here or a remote one works great. At this point, you're free to make a choice based on code-management and not dep-management, as to whether or not to break things into different SBT projects.

EDIT: so in the end, if you want to move a module out of the multi-project SBT thing, you just need to add regular maven deps to whatever code base is requesting the other

Answer (score -1):

My opinion: Skip the sub-projects. Splitting a project is nice, when you publish them as independent projects. But multiple projects make also trouble: It is quite hard to get good and stable interfaces between multiple projects.

I would split a project into multiple projects as late as possible. Dependency management (especially cyclical dependencies), refactoring (especially moving of classes) and tool support in general (especially IDE integration) is much better with only one big project.

Things like measuring code coverage can also become surprisingly difficult, when the coverage spans multiple projects.

Custom scopes and six sub-projects: In my opinion this is totally over engineered. Stay with one project, get the whole thing running and split it later (if necessary).

Comment: But it already is split. I'm trying to deal effectively with a large existing codebase :)

Comment: @MyseriousDan: Poor you. Perhaps you can at least merge some of the sub projects. While being nice in theory, splitting a code base among different sub-projects usually leads to much trouble in practice.